# How to calculate age from birth date and display it with Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I have a problem with displaying data with age who I must calculate with birth_date attribute

**Controller**

```
public function listageAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $query = $em->createQuery(
         'select DATE_DIFF( CURRENT_DATE(),p.dateNaissance)
          from PersonnelBundle:Personnel p'
    );

    $personnels = $query->getResult();

    return $this->render('PersonnelBundle:Default:listage.html.twig');
}
```

**View**

```
{% for personnel in personnels %}
    <li> {{ personnel.nomP }} {{ personnel.prenomP }}  </li>
    <li> {{ personnel.age}} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

I have this error:

> Variable "personnels" does not exist in PersonnelBundle:Default:listage.html.twig at line 6

Answer (score 10):

Your problem is not calculating a date, you haven't injected the $personnels variable into a twig template. Take 5 minutes to read the documentation on views.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html

Specifically: this example is relevant to you.

```
$this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
    'variable_name' => 'variable_value',
));
```

Comment: i have injected the $personnels variable into my twig template:         return $this->render('PersonnelBundle:Default:listage.html.twig', array('personnels'=> $personnels));                                                       and now i have this error:   Undefined variable: personnels